# Cannot open .tif file due to 'cannot identify image file' error

Tags: image, load, python-imaging-library, tiff

The file exists, path is correct, however I cannot load the .tif file. Please send help?
Here's the code ..

```
import os
from PIL import Image

name = 'PE-0D8-4m-10s-0001_00009_bbo.tif'

THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, name)

image = Image.open(filename)
```

And here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\owner\MATLAB Drive\Python\imageload.py", line 23, in <module>
    image = Image.open(filename)

  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2862, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'C:\\Users\\owner\\MATLAB Drive\\Python\\PE-0D8-4m-10s-0001_00009_bbo.tif'
```

Comment: Could be a [BigTIFF](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html) file. Try to open the file with [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).

Comment: @cgohlke You are a freaking genius. Worked out brilliantly. I have to ask a question tho how do you know the file is BigTIFF or TIFF or whatnot when you look at the .tif extension files?

Comment: If the first four bytes in a file are `b'II\x2B\x00'` or `b'MM\x00\x2B'`, it is likely a BigTIFF file.