# Opening Tif file with PIL "PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file"

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-imaging-library, tiff

I've a huge TIF file of shape (39906, 30365, 4). I want to use it on PyQt5, however when I use PIL to open the image it gives the error "PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file".
I've searched and it seems that PIL can open TIF/TIFF files, but it has to be 8bit and my image is 8bit.

What could I do fix it? Is the file to large to be open by PIL? Is there another option to open a huge TIF to be used with PyQt5?

It's not necessary to open the whole image. Actually, if I could open a 25% scaled version of the original would be better.

Pillow version = 7.2.0

Comment: Try opening it with QImage

Comment: Is that 4.8G? Maybe you could try scikit-image to open the file? There is a difference between TIF files < 4G and files larger. (Actually I don't remember the cutoff). Possibly the easiest solution would be to make a scaled copy of the file?

Comment: @alec I tried. But it says that the QImage is null image. If I use QPixmap, the same happens.

Comment: @matt it's 1.37 GB, but I'll try scikit-image. How could I scale copy the tif file?

Comment: You could resize it in Terminal before you start with **ImageMagick** using `magick BIGBOY.TIF -resize 25% result.tif` - replace `magick` with `convert` if using v6.

Comment: 40k x 30k * 4 takes 4.8GB in memory.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You're right. It should be 4.8GB. This is shown when I use "magick identify BIGBOY.tif": "BIGBOY.tif TIFF64 39906x30365 39906x30365+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.37325GiB 0.000u 0:00.052". 
I've tried the magick resize, but I got an error about it couldn't extend the cache. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860654/cannot-open-tif-file-due-to-cannot-identify-image-file-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having issues handling very large images, consider using `libvips`, either in your Python code or in the Terminal. It is very fast and frugal with memory.

Here's an example for Terminal:

```
vipsthumbnail BIGBOY.TIF --size 10000x -o small.tif     # reduce width to 10000px
```

And see `usingVIPSandShrink()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57717879/2836621).